# Why does next-i18next need next-i18next.config.js?

Tags: next-i18next

I wonder why does next-i18next need next-i18next.config.js.

My guess is that i18n-related data declared in next.config.js can be pulled out, but I wonder why it needs to exist as a separate file. In my case, Front is configured as a monorepo, so in that case i need to create next-i18next.config.js in every monorepo.

Having a separate file creates a lot of additional work, which is inconvenient. Is there a solution?

I pushed the contents of i18next.config.js into next.config.js.

Answer (score 0):

`i18n-related data` in the nextjs config only concerns a small subset of keys in `next-i18next.config.js` related to router and locales, which is not enough to run a proper `i18next` instance for handling translations.
If creating an extra config is too much work for you, then you should rethink if you need multilang support in the first place, because it's a permanent overhead in the form of extra files and general code complexity for every component/page down the line anyway, the extra config is a drop in the ocean compared to that.